# AWS EC2: keep running node.js after exit console

Tags: node.js, apache, express, amazon-ec2

I use aws ec2 to host web server with node.js and apache.

So far, I always need to login ec2 through terminal to run `npm start`.

I wanna make it keep running even if Im not on terminal. How am I supposed to setup for it?

I turned on `https`, but nothing happened.

I appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using the screen command:

```
screen
```

You will reach a new bash prompt for that screen. Run your app.

To detach the screen, press `Ctrl+A`, then `D` to detach from that screen.

To reattach screen when you next SSH in, use

```
screen -ls
```

to see detached screens and use

```
screen -r xxxxx
```

with the screen number to reattach that screen.